# Decrypt AES changing the last letter

Tags: encryption, aes

I need to encrypt some data in a client application and verify it later in a server application.
I'm assuming that if the message was decrypted then it was from a valid client, since the key is necessary to create a valid crypted string.

I'using AES implementation from MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=netframework-4.8

I choose AES because in my tests it generated a short string. It is an important issue for me.

```
public static void Main()
    {
        string original = "message to secure";

        using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create())
        {
            myAes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String("AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODw=="); 

            byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(original, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

            var encryptedString = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);

            string roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString), myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

            Console.WriteLine("Encrypted: " + encryptedString); 
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypted: " + roundtrip); 
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    { 
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
        byte[] encrypted;

        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        return encrypted;
    }

    static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    { 
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

        string plaintext = null;

        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return plaintext;
    }
```

But I noticed that if there is a change in the last caracter (before equals sign) the string is decrypted as nothing was changed.

For example:

HdPAmfHTxkMmj8D3VelWjH2A8iGm6gnzzPYGNT5NR14= was generated and I changed it to HdPAmfHTxkMmj8D3VelWjH2A8iGm6gnzzPYGNT5NR1**5**= and a got the same result.

Could someone give me some guidance in how I guarantee that if the generated string was change it cannot be decrypted?

Comment: I don't know exactly what's going on there, but AES works on blocks of exactly 256 bits, and that string is a base-64 encoding of a block of 258 bits. That means, there's two bits of _padding_ in the string. You changed the lowest-order bit of the last character from a zero to a one. If that was one of the two padding bits, then it might be perfectly reasonable for the change to have no effect on decryption of the string.

Comment: P.S., What does, "...and verify it" mean? If any non-padding bit of the cyphertext gets flipped, then I would expect the result of decoding it to look pretty random. But will your application be able to _reliably_ tell the difference between 256 random bits and some kind of meaningful input?

Comment: By "verify it" I mean to be able to decrypt it. I was suposing that only a string that was encrypted with the specific key can be decrypted with it. So, if I got it right, I just need to change the padding of the algorithm to 0 for remove those "can be changed" caracters?

Comment: Any string of 256 bits is a valid input to the basic AES encryption and decryption algorithms; and any string of 256 bits is a possible output. AES decryption has no way to tell whether the cypher text is "valid" or not. It's entirely up to your application to tell whether it can make some kind of sense of the result. If the plaintext has a lot of redundancy (i.e., has a low density of information), then that may be an easy task, but if your data is very compact, then you may want to use some kind of a _[checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum)_ to verify that nothing has changed.

Comment: Any string of 256 is valid, but only the one encrypted with a AES key can be decrypted with the same key. Isn't?

Comment: Thank you Solomon. You also helped to figure out my real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solomon has more or less hit the nail on the head with all their comments.

> I'm assuming that if the message was decrypted then it was from a valid client, since the key is necessary to create a valid crypted string.

This base assumption is actually false.  There are a number of scenarios (in unauthenticated modes of operation) where decryption can succeed even if the ciphertext has been modified - resulting in a plaintext different from the one that was originally encrypted.

Recall that AES is a block cipher.  It transforms one block of 128 bits to another block of 128 bits.  The only other variables are the key used, and the operation (e.g. encrypt or decrypt).  There is no mechanism to detect if the block of 128 bits passed in has been modified since some prior operation - AES isn't aware of that.  It is simply a keyed transformation function.

To avoid this problem, use an authenticated mode of operation like GCM, or use an HMAC.  See the examples in [this repository](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples) for an example of use GCM in C#.

---

As to the second issue:

> But I noticed that if there is a change in the last caracter (before equals sign) the string is decrypted as nothing was changed.

Technically *nothing* was changed - this is a "feature".  Each base64 character represents 6 bits of the original data.  This means that, unless your ciphertext length is divisible by both 8 and 6, there are bits "left over".  See the example below where we encode 16-bits:

```
Raw                      : { 0x00, 0x01 }
Binary                   : 00000000 00000001

Base64                   : AAE=
Binary (6 Digit Grouping): 000000 000000 000100
Binary (8 Digit Grouping): 00000000 00000001 00
                                             ^^ these bits are irrelevant
```

In essence, nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you Luke. I definetly have to work on my crypto skills. You have gave me a light to work on my problem. I'll check GCM out.